# Table doesn't exist error during deployment of an ATG project in JBoss

Tags: jboss, atg

I am getting the following tables doesn't exist error while deploying a simple ATG project in JBoss:

dbc_user, dbc_buyer_billing, paf_reg_url, dbc_org_billing,
   paf_gear_user, paf_gu_params, paf_gr_uparams, paf_user_param,
   paf_user_prmvals, paf_usr_rgn, paf_usr_rgn_gr, paf_usr_pgfld,
   paf_usr_cpgfld, paf_usr_ppgfld, paf_usr_cm, paf_usr_pg,
   paf_usr_pg_rgn

Where can I find the sql scripts for the above tables? I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

When you executed your `CIM` installer you probably didn't select the same set of modules that you are including in your build process. For example the `dbc_user`, `dbc_buyer_billing` and `dbc_org_billing` tables are all included in the `b2bcommerce_ddl.sql` script based in the `B2BCommerce` module.

The missing `PAF_xxx` tables all seem to be from the `Portals` module in the `profile_ddl.sql`.

So either redo your database setup using `CIM` and include the correct modules or, when you execute the `runAssembler` command to build your ATG project, remove the modules you don't need.